# 64 vs 32 Bit Performance on Medium Sized Computer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any benefit from installing Windows 7 64-bit when you have less than 4GB or RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/183201/is-there-any-benefit-from-installing-windows-7-64-bit-when-you-have-less-than-4gb)

I am getting ready to install Windows 7 on a laptop with 4GB of memory.  I know there are advantages to using the 64-Bit version when you have large amounts of memory (i.e., > 4GB).  Are there any advantages to the 64-Bit version when you have 4GB or less?

Comment: This has already been discussed: [Is there any benefit from installing Windows 7 64-bit when you have less than 4GB or RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/183201/).

Answer (score 1):

More than 2GB memory can be addressed per-process on a 64-bit system, allowing memory hungry applications to perform better. Another advantage is the access to more registers, and thus, 64-bit integers :)

Although with all the big integer libraries we have available today, doing processing on larger numbers is possible on 32-bit operating systems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Only when running heavy multimedia or scientific software, due to the increased size and number of registers available.